# Find the position of a body at $t=2\pi$ that was traveling the curve $r(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, t)$ and left the curve at $t=\pi$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

> There's a curve $r(t)=(\cos t, \sin t, t)$ and a body that is traveling the curve. At $t=\pi$ the body leaves the curve. Given that no external forces influence the body, where (which point) will it be situated at $t=2\pi$?

So we can suppose that the body will just travel in the direction of the tangent once it leaves the curve. We can find this direction:
$$
r'(t)=<-\sin t, \cos t, 1>
$$
$$
r'(t=\pi)=<0,-1,1>
$$

My next step would be to find the line with the same direction vector as $r'(t)$, so we need to find the starting point which is $r(t=\pi)=(-1,0,\pi)$ so now we have the line:
$$
l: (-1,0,\pi)+t(0,-1,1)
$$

So now we can just plug in $2\pi$ into line equation to get the point where the body will:
$$
2\pi(0,-1,1)=(0,-2\pi,2\pi)
$$

I don't think the solution is correct and I feel that unit vector tangent is involved somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Only the $t$-parametrization of $l$ is slightly off the mark. It should be
$$l:\qquad t\mapsto l(t):=r(\pi)+(t-\pi)r'(\pi)$$
instead. Note that at time $t=\pi$ the running point on $l$ starts at $r(\pi)$ and proceeds with constant speed $r'(\pi)$ along $l$. It follows
that 
$$l(2\pi)=(-1,0,\pi)+\pi(0,-1,1)=\ldots$$

Comment: I can't understand why we need to subtract $\pi$ from $t$. The particle starts to move on the line at $t=\pi$ but we accounted for that by calculating the starting point of $l$. Why does our direction vector needs to be adjusted yet?

Comment: I think I got it: we need to subtract $\pi$ because we already traveled $\pi$. So we need to compensate for that right?